# Mechanism for induction of electrical charges

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current

Usually we are just told that if we bring in a positive charge plate close to a neutral one, then the neutral one picks up charge due to induction. However, in no sources I've read (yet) have described how this exactly happens. For example in page-271 to 272 of the [NCERT physics textbook](https://ncert.nic.in/ncerts/l/leph108.pdf), it is described how if we blindly follow ampere's law, a contradiction is occurred by varying the surfaces associated and this contradiction is solved by introducing displacement current.

Now, considering the above context, would it be correct to think that mechanism of charge induction is actually happening to a sort of current between charged and uncharged bodies?

If the above conclusion I've made is correct, I seek a reference to where I can read more about this.

[I saw this explanation on wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_induction#Charging_an_object_by_induction) and the wiki explains it's due to the field caused by the opposite charge brought close to the sruface. However, no where on the internet can I found quantitative calculations for this.

We see that even in a electrical circuit that it's the electrical field of the battery which pushes the electron, but we explain the flow as current. So, could we associate a current here?

Comment: No! the displacement current is due to the fact that the electric field between the capacitor is changing. The
existence of a new induction effect in which a changing electric field
is accompanied by a magnetic field.

Comment: On the neutral plate a negative charge is developed, I am thinking this negative charge is being transfered from positive plate via the displacement current or is what I've written wrong itself? @YoungKindaichi

Comment: [Here is a pic I found](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.miniphysics.com%2Fuy1-displacement-current.html&psig=AOvVaw3MRzyIcwISrHc49-gmDMpj&ust=1614894208347000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCJDWvPCLle8CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD) it certainly seems to suggest to me that the displacement current is how the charge is being transfered

Comment: Can you explain this a little further?  Would it be correct to think that mechanism of charge induction is actually happening to a sort of current between charged and uncharged bodies?

Comment: So, we say the induced charges when a charged object comes near a conducting surface as induction. However, the mechanism of 'how' this happen is not eddscribed. Since displacement current is a thing, couldn't we explain that induction charge transfer occurs due to induction?

@YoungKindaichi

Comment: Have you tried looking at Wikipedia? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_induction#Charging_an_object_by_induction This explains the mechanism for charge by induction.

Comment: I don't think mechanism for induction is discussed @d_b

Comment: @Buraian It is discussed in the section I linked "Charging an object by induction." I know it is there because I read it. Alternatively, you can find an explanation in any university level physics textbook.

Comment: Only the first paragraph discusses it "ge, the above object is momentarily connected through a conductive path to electrical ground, which is a large reservoir of both positive and negative charges, some of the negative charges in the ground will flow into the object, under the attraction of the nearby positive charge. When the contact with ground is broken, the object is left with a net negative charge." , now this doesn't tell precisely how the charge moves. @d_b

Comment: Sure it does. The charges move in response to the electric force applied to them. I'm not sure what more you want. If I said "A ball that is dropped from a building falls because the Earth exerts a gravitational force on the ball" would you object that this does not tell us "precisely how the ball moves"? Anyway, I think this discussion has gotten too long for the comments. If you are still unsatisfied, maybe you could edit your question to clarify what exactly you want to know or what is missing from this explanation.